# FireEvent.click doesn't check an input of type checkbox in React Testing Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

Having the following elements visible in console after `screen.debug()`:

**first checkbox**

```
<input
  type="checkbox"
  aria-label="checkbox"
  name="checkbox-array"
  value="first"
  checked="" // here is the difference
  id="first"
/>
```

**second checkbox**

```
<input
  type="checkbox"
  aria-label="checkbox"
  name="checkbox-array"
  value="second"
  id="second"
/>
```

I want to write a unit test that:

- selects the second checkbox
- verify that it isn't checked
- fire an event to click on it
- verify that it's clicked now

So here's the test:

```
  it('should select second option when clicked', () => {
    const secondElement = screen.getAllByLabelText('checkbox')[1]; // selects the correct element
    expect(secondElement).toBeInTheDocument(); // passes
    expect(secondElement).not.toHaveAttribute('checked', ''); // passes 
    // screen.debug(); // added just for debugging
    fireEvent.click(secondElement); // clicks on the element, it should check it now 
    // screen.debug(); // added just for debugging
    expect(secondElement).toHaveAttribute('checked', ''); // fails. it is still unchecked
  });
```

Is there any reason that `fireEvent.click` isn't updating the element? Or how should it be fixed?

Comment: Can you provide the component where these inputs are rendered? You will need some state management to change the checked status of your checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

Your test needs to wait for the asynchonous action of updating the UI to complete i.e. waiting for the screen to update after the checkbox is clicked.

Try changing your code to:

```
it('should select second option when clicked', async () => {
    const secondElement = screen.getAllByLabelText('checkbox')[1]; // selects the correct element
    expect(secondElement).toBeInTheDocument(); // passes
    expect(secondElement).not.toHaveAttribute('checked', ''); // passes 
    // screen.debug(); // added just for debugging
    fireEvent.click(secondElement); // clicks on the element, it should check it now 
    // screen.debug(); // added just for debugging

    // Wait for the expected UI state
    await waitFor(() => expect(secondElement).toHaveAttribute('checked', ''));
  });
```